# How to I save a dataFrame instead of loading it (from web) every time I run my code?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, pycharm

My code starts with "pd.read_csv(link, low_memory=False)"
There I have extensive data on flights (a month), so for the project I need to analyse 12 of this df and I have the code to do it, but it takes waaaaaay too long, evn after I drop some columns. I'm new to coding, so might've missed something obvious. I'm coding on PyCharm using python 2.7 and pandas.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to_pickle() or to_feather (and then read_pickle() or read_feather()) so you can store the data locally. Do no use Python 2.7 anymore. It is obsolete since too much time.

Comment: Thank you @GiacomoCatenazzi ! I actually thought my laptop was a problem, but now it all works. Ok sure I'll switch. :)